# How to make condition on history goBack function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

There is page someUrl/posts/postId with button which trigger history.goBack function. Can get to that page from someUrl/posts or from home page or directly paste to address bar. If is third option I want to hide back button on page. Is there any condition I can make to app figure out is history.goBack function possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the history.length is greater than 0.

```
if (history.length >= 1) {
    history.goBack(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me!